# javascript: class method access deep function

Tags: javascript

Is it  possible to access method/function m1 from instance of MyObjGraph?
Thanks in advance for your answers

```
class MyObjGraph 
{
    constructor(id) 
    {
        this.drawGraph(id);
    }
    drawGraph(id)
    {
        var inId = id;
        function m1()
        {
            alert(inId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. In this example m1 is available only to the scope inside drawGraph. If you need a function available anywhere in the class, define it in the class same as drawGraph.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? (Spoiler: the answer is "no".)

Comment: no it is a standalone function  (not a method of ```MyObjGraph``` class) and it is known i the scope of ```MyObjGraph.drawGraph()```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, because it is considered as local function so the scope wouldn't be outside the drawGraph method. Only drawGraph method can access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can slightly modify the code, you could expose the inner method to the "outside":

```js
class MyObjGraph {
    constructor(id) {
        this.drawGraph(id);
    }
    drawGraph(id){
        var inId = id;
        function m1(){
            alert(inId);
        }
        
        return {  //  <-------- return an object of everything you want to be exposed
          m1
        }
    }
}

const instance = new MyObjGraph();

instance.drawGraph("123").m1()
```

### Explanation:

In your original code, the method `drawGraph` does not return anything, therefor it only executes code, and nothing inside of it is accessible.

For anything to be accessible *directly* from a function, the function needs to have a `return` statement, so when you invoke that function you get something in "return"... and that something, in this case below, is an Object with a single property: `m1` (reference to the `m1` inner function)